# Question about the risk analysis.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, finance, risk-assessment

[image]

In the above one can see the detail of this question, I am beginner in this kind of mathematics. I will be very greatful if any one can help me to solve them.

Comment: Have you tried to look at the variances of each of those distributions?

Comment: What part are you having problem with? Do you not know much about probability distributions, about utility functions or about the hypotheses on which decisions are supposed to be based?

Comment: No, I have not look at the variances, I am very new in this course if one can help me with just part 1, than I can continue with the other parts.

Comment: Hi Kiran, how did you find my answer? Please comment if you have any questions. Did you know that you can accept answers if you like them by clicking the check mark ✓ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/). You currently have 13 questions and 0 accepts. If you accept answers to enough of them you'll be able to upvote as well :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming this is an assignment question so I'm just going to try to point you in the right direction (and only on the first part: you said in a comment that this was what you wanted help with).

> Do any decision makers with (increasing) utility function agree about preferring risk $X_1$ to $X_2$?

The expectations of $X_1$ and $X_2$ are equal: $E(X_1)=E(X_2)$. So there would be no reason to prefer $X_1$ or $X_2$ on this basis.

The question is asking if there is any increasing utility function $u(x)$ such that
$$E(u(X_1)) > E(u(X_2)) \\ \iff \\
\sum_{x=0}^{10}u(x)Pr(X_1=x) > \sum_{x=0}^{15}u(x)Pr(X_2=x) \\ \iff \\
\sum_{x=0}^{10}u(x)\binom{10}{x}0.5^x0.5^{1-x} > \sum_{x=0}^{15}u(x)\binom{15}{x}(1/3)^x(2/3)^{1-x}$$

Note that $X_1$'s probability of success, 1/2, is greater than $X_2$'s probability of success, 1/3. But $X_2$ still has the same expectation as $X_1$ because with $X_2$ the maximum number of successes you can get, 15, is greater than the maximum number of successes you can get for $X_1$, 10. This suggests that *if* such a utility function exists, it is one which disproportionately rewards a lower number of successes.

The graph below shows the line $y=x$ in black for the utility function $u(x)=x$, corresponding to $E(u(X))=E(X)$. There are two other lines in green and red: if one of these corresponded to a utility function where decision makers would prefer $X_1$ to $X_2$, which one would it be?

[image]

Comment: thanks for explaining me everything regarding how to accept the answer as I was not familiar with this before as I am very new user here. Now regarding the question, I was thinking that the decision maker will go for green line, if I am wrong please rectify me in it. Thanks

Comment: No problem explaining, it's usual to advise new users (you also now have enough rep to upvote -- my policy when asking qs is to upvote answers I get which address my question and are useful). Re the decision itself, what I suggest you do is to go into excel (or libreoffice, or use R if you know it), and simply compare and contrast. You'll learn a lot. The green line is $x^2$ (the red line if I remember rightly is $\sqrt{x}$). In Excel you can use `BINOMDIST` to get binomial probabilities, so put these in one column. Put the $x^2$s in another column. Use `SUMPRODUCT` to get your expectation.